# "Powers" to a Power: MultipLY

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve

(x^3)^4? Would the answer be x^81 or x^27?

The outside exponent 4 confuses me. I remember choosing 27 but not sure why.

Comment: if you're looking for a really good explanation of the rules of exponents, take a gander at http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html

Answer (score 2):

Neither. The answer is $x^3 \cdot x^3 \cdot x^3 \cdot x^3 = x^{3+3+3+3} = x^{3 \cdot 4} = x^{12}$.

Comment: +2 - If I could.

Answer (score 2):

The rule for expressions like this is $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$. This is very different from $x^{a^b}$, obviously. What you would need to do in that case is apply the highest exponent first.